# How to restore my desktop?

Tags: unity, launcher, panel

I lost my desktop. I see some files that I left on the desktop but I don't see any of the menus. How could I restore the menus? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

**In terminal use the following command :**

```
unity --reset
```